# Multi-tenancy DNS setup - how to?

Tags: dns, automation, multi-tenant

Sorry for the completely newbie question, but I really do not seem to understand how this would be done.

Can you automate the creation of sub-domains for a multi-tenant application that is  hosted?  Say for example a new customer signs up and specifies the sub-domain of choice.  user1.mysite.com.

How do I automate the creation of the sub-domain and have it point to the single instance of my application? If yes, how do you go about doing this?  Any samples or links would be most appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: What you are describing is actually a Single-Tenant architecture.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you have owned the domain, you can create a subdomain manually in the configpage of your domain provider. The provider will have to config the subdomain for you(input subdomain and IP mapping into DNS Server). This could delay for some hours.
After that, you can create another mapping between your documentroot(where you application lives) and subdomain with . see more details [here](http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm).

Answer (score 9):

You don't create subdomains, you create a wildcard DNS record.

```
*.mysite.com A 1.2.3.4
```